# Strange path references to Javascript files?

Tags: html, path, url-rewriting

In a HTML page references to Javascript files are rewritten with one additional subdirectory at the end:

/+sfgRmluamFuX1R5cGU9amF2YV9zY3JpcHQmRmluamFuX0xhbmc9dGV4dC9qYXZhc2NyaXB0+.

Why is that and can it be a source to potential problems?

In our source code we have Javascript includes like this one:

On development machines and the test server everything works fine. However, when installed on a production server, the code is somehow changed and looks like this one:

This is for every script. Since we are experiencing problems with some of the Javascripts, I wonder whether this can be the cause of them. 
I googled for quite a while and did not find any good explanation for this code addition, the only one I found was that this can be generated by a proxy server.

Comment: Perhaps you should make the title a little shorter!

Comment: This must be the most ridiculous subject line ever. Please keep the subject line SHORT!

Comment: I am sorry, this is my first time here.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Proxy issue. See Ivan's solution to his own problem.

*Is this really HTML? You wouldn't happen to be in ASP.NET would you, cause that looks alot like a cookieless session string.
You can very easily test to make sure you're scripts are loaded by checking firebug's net tab, or failing that just putting an `alert('LOADED!')` in them.*

Answer (score 0):

We use Java and JSF with JBoss.

Originally the code is like this one:

```
<script src="/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"><!--

//--></script>
```

And it gets rewritten to this one:

```
<script src="/js/tiny_mce/+sfgRmluamFuX1R5cGU9amF2YV9zY3JpcHQmRmluamFuX0xhbmc9dGV4dC9qYXZhc2NyaXB0+/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"><!--

//--></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely a proxy problem. We accessed it from another place than ours and it worked and these funny additions did not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for all the guys that can have the same problem. It was due to our security policy. We added the website into our trusted zone and it was fine.